# Regarding Kerrighed Clustering

Tags: cluster

Is it possible to do a [Kerrighed clustering](http://www.kerrighed.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)  in Red Hat . if yes , could please provide an idea to accomplish this clustering .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not.

From the [FAQ](http://www.kerrighed.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ):

> Can I use Kerrighed with any version
>   of Linux ?
>
> No. Kerrighed is made of a patch to
>   the Linux kernel plus some other
>   tools. Hence it is designed on a
>   particular version of a Linux kernel.
>   You can find the Linux version to use
>   the installation manual for each
>   Kerrighed version.

Red Hat (and Fedora/CentOS) systems are notorious for using custom kernels, so it will very probably not work by default; it could *probably* be made to work with some effort, but then you'd be on your own if something goes wrong.